# Не работает :style="backgroundImage" во Vue

Tags: vue.js

У меня есть слайдер - swiper. Слайды я создаю через v-for, где каждому слайду я присваиваю название и фоновую картинку. Проблема заключается в присвоении картинки. Она находится в `assets/2.jpg`. Я добавляю ее через `:style="{backgroundImage:` url(${slide.img})`}"` (не работает), но если я добавляю картинку через css, то в окне разработчика я вижу ее путь как `background-image: url(/img/2.b8261e45.jpg)`(работает)

Код:

```js
data(){
    return{
      slides: [
        {tittle: 'Slide 1', img: '../assets/1.jpg'},
        {tittle: 'Slide 2', img: '../assets/2.jpg'}
        ]
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div v-for="slide in slides"
       :key="slide.tittle"
       :style="{backgroundImage: `url(${slide.img})`}"
       class="swiper-slide">
    <span class="swiper-tittle">
      {{ slide.tittle }}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: надо смотреть ошибки в консоле

Comment: в консоле нет ошибок